# Stack Exchange login hangs on Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: support, api, authentication, c#, oauth2

I am working on a Stack Exchange App (*Stack App* for Windows 10 PC/Mobile and Windows 8.1 Mobile).

I have a user login set up and using the `WebAuthenticationBroker` in Universal Windows Platform, to get the access_token. This works fine on Windows 10 Desktop.

But when it comes to Windows 10 Mobile, The login page Hangs after tapping on `Login with StackExchange`.
By the time I am typing this question, it's almost 28 Mins and it is still running. I tried to enter the URL on my Mobile browser ( Microsoft Edge ) and still the same but it works on my Windows 10 Machine and Tablet.

Below is the screenshot. If you see it hangs @ this page not giving me option to enter my username and password.

[image]

During my last 10 Mins of search on this topic using query strings `Application Hangs`,`Login hangs`,`Authentication Hangs`, `WebBrowser Hangs` I was redirected to [this question](https://stackapps.com/questions/4244/desktop-login-url-webbrowser-hangs-net-javascript-endless-loop)

Can anyone point me as to what could be the issue?

**Part of my **AuthenticationBroker**:

```
string str = string.Format("https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id={0}&scope={1}&redirect_uri={2}", client_id, "no_expiry", "https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success");
WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, new Uri(str),new Uri("https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success"));
if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
{
    RetVal = OutputToken(WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData);
    _class = await GetProfileData(RetVal);
}
```

Comment: @BrockAdams This is after OpenID login options. As I mentioned in my question, This happens after I Tap on Login with StackExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the structure of Authentication on my App. For windows 10, I use AuthenticationBroker but for Windows 10 Phone I used the old WebView Model and completed login implementation.